# Want to create an event system with Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express

I want to create an event system to communicate between multiple NPM plugins installed in the same application. I want to create two types of events:

- Synchronous events
- Asynchronous events

I am having trouble managing the second type as well as stopping jobs that run for too long.

I have the following code to manage my events (details omitted for clarity)

```
function dispatchEvent(eventId) {
  var jobs = getJobsForEvent(eventId) // Returns a list of callbacks
  jobs.forEach(function runJob() {
    if (job.toString().startsWith("async")) {
      // I want to add it to the database and run it later from my CRON job
    }
    else {
      job(); // How do I stop it if it runs for too long?
    }
  });
}
```

I have tried saving the code directly to the database and running it later using `eval`, but it fails due to variables not being present and required packages not being imported.

How do I execute asynchronous events and stop synchronous events if they run for too long?

Comment: What does SQL server have to to with your question?

Comment: SQL server is the database I am trying to create the job queue in

Comment: Sure but it doesn't seem part of what you are stuck on... I.e. it doesn't seem you need SQL server expert's

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I was thinking about SQL server types and got a little confused.